# How to test a component base on material ui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following component, that is build with https://material-ui-next.com/.

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppBar, Toolbar } from 'material-ui';
import { Typography } from 'material-ui';
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from 'material-ui/styles';
import {lightBlue} from 'material-ui/colors';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main:lightBlue['A700']
    },
    text: {
      primary: '#fff',
    }
  },
});

const View = (props) => (
  <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <AppBar position="static">
      <Toolbar>
      <Typography variant="title">
        {props.title}
      </Typography>          
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
);
export default View;
```

I am trying to write a test for it:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import View from '../Views/View';
import { Typography } from 'material-ui';

it('renders', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<View title='Welcome' />);
  expect(wrapper.find('Typography').text()).toEqual('Welcome');
});
```

How to write a test for a component, that is using `material-ui` components? In the case above, I tried to figure out, if the component contains `Welcome`.
I read https://material-ui-next.com/guides/testing/, but it is not clear, how can I write a test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPD: API changed from `shallow` to `mount`**

Did you tried to use their API [described here](https://material-ui-next.com/guides/testing/#createshallow-options-shallow)?
Probably your test can look something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createMount } from 'material-ui/test-utils';
import View from '../Views/View';
import { Typography } from 'material-ui';

it('renders', () => {
  const mount = createMount();
  const wrapper = mount(<View title='Welcome' />);
  expect(wrapper.find('Typography').text()).toEqual('Welcome');
});
```

Comment: Yes, but it says: `We expose a createShallow() function for this situation. However, you will most likely not need it most of the time. Shallow rendering was created to test components in isolation. This means without leaking child implementation details such as the context.` That's why I avoid to use it.

Comment: But you choose to use `enzyme`s `shallow` which basically do the same(it hides children implementation details)! You need to choose what to test - all components tree with all implementation (use `mount` for this purpose), or just top component(use `shallow`). BTW if you want to write unit tests - you will need `shallow`ly test each component most of the time, it's suggested in `jest` documentation.

Comment: Then how to test a property, for example the property `title` from the component `View`?

Comment: First for your answer. What is the top component of the `View`? `MuiThemeProvider`?

Comment: I don't know inner implementation of `createMount()` by `material-ui/test-utils`. It seems that it do what it's description states https://material-ui-next.com/guides/testing/#createmount-options-mount - creates correct context for testing mounted element (`View` in your case). This is an answer to your question, because now all features of `enzyme` are available for you to test your component.